# Application specific implementation of a class method

Tags: excel, vba, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I have a library (add-in) with a class that is used in a few small applications. I want to provide a `Save` method to that class, which 
will depend on the application that is running.
To solve it I am trying to use a strategy pattern(I might be misunderstanding the pattern), but my understanding of the subject is lacking. At runtime I am providing a strategy class that will handle the saving. Common class exposes a `Save` method that relays it to the provided strategy class. But to keep consistency it appears to me that common class have to implement the strategy interface as well.

IRecord (Common Class) Interface:

```
Public Function DoSomething(): End Function
Public Function SetStrategy(ByVal Strategy As IDatabaseStrategy): End Function
```

Record (Common Class) implementation:

```
Private RecordStrategy As IDatabaseStrategy
Implements IRecord
Implements IDatabaseStrategy 'Implements this interface to have Save method
Private Function IRecord_DoSomething():
    'does whatever the class is supposed to do
End Function
Private Function IRecord_SetStrategy(ByVal Strategy As IDatabaseStrategy)
    Set RecordStrategy = Strategy
End Function
Private Function IDataBaseStrategy_Save()
    RecordStrategy.Save
End Function
```

Strategy Interface and Implementation:

- IDatabaseStrategy: `Public Function Save():End Function`
- DataBaseStrategyA:

  ```
  Implements IDatabaseStrategy
  Private Function IDataBaseStrategy_Save()
  Debug.Print "Saving to database A"
  End Function
  ```
- DataBaseStrategyB:

  ```
  Implements IDatabaseStrategy
  Private Function IDataBaseStrategy_Save()
  Debug.Print "Saving to database B"
  End Function
  ```

Application Module:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ApplicationA()
    Dim Item As IRecord
    Set Item = New Record
    Dim Strategy As IDatabaseStrategy
    Set Strategy = New DatabaseStrategyA
    Item.SetStrategy Strategy 'this would normally be done with constructor
    Dim ItemToSave As IDatabaseStrategy
    Set ItemToSave = Item
    ItemToSave.Save
End Sub

Public Sub ApplicationB()
    Dim Item As IRecord
    Set Item = New Record
    Dim Strategy As IDatabaseStrategy
    Set Strategy = New DatabaseStrategyB
    Item.SetStrategy Strategy 'this would normally be done with constructor
    Dim ItemToSave As IDatabaseStrategy
    Set ItemToSave = Item
    ItemToSave.Save
End Sub
```

With this approach I have to have `Record` implement `Database strategy` to have `Save` method and then recast `Item` from `IRecord` to `IDatabaseStrategy`to use it. I think I am using the pattern incorrectly, so my question is - how do I provide a `DatabaseStrategy` to a `Record` so that I do not have to recast the object and possibly without implementing `IDatabaseStrategy`  in `Record`?
Alternatives that I have considered:

- Wrapping `DatabaseStrategy` around `Record` specific to the `Record` and the application (`DatabaseStrategy.Create(Record).Save`)
- Exposing `DatabaseStrategy` as a member of the `Record` but then it seems that application has to know that `DatabaseStrategy` is a member of the record (`Record.DatabaseStrategy.Save`).

Comment: I can conceive an `IStorageStrategy` with `DatabaseStorageStrategy` and `FlatFileStorageStrategy` implementations... but if all that changes between the two is the connection string used, then the setup seems overkill. Now if I understand the purpose of a `Record`, I don't think a `Record` should implement `IDatabaseStrategy` here - how about having a `Record` parameter on the `Save` method?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I was thinking of having multiple classes (say `Record` and an entirely different `Contact`) have the same method `Save` so that I can pass them to a `Sub` that will invoke that method. But that means each of those have to implement `IDatabaseStrategy` and it indeed seems misplaced. Currently I use it as a wrapper: `RecordStrategy.Create(Record)` or `ContactStrategy.Create(Contact)` and then pass it to a `Sub` that invokes `Save`. I guess I am wondering if there is a better established way for it?

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you have in mind. Can you [edit] to clarify? Using placeholder names ("ThingA", "ThingB") isn't helping. Also, read up on repository & unit of work OOP patterns, commonly used for abstracting database/storage operations from the rest of the code in an OOP paradigm.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thank you for the suggestions, will do!

Comment: If you want a lightweight implementation then you could always pass in a string containing the name of the method to call back on for the implementation and then use `Application.Run` to call it  (will need to match parameter count for each implementation)

Comment: Might help to incorporate this link into text of the question https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Comment: If your intention is to save the data out to different locations then all you need is a `destination` parameter on your `.Save` function. Pass it whatever you want, database a,b, or z. This keeps you from having to update the strategy when destinations change. It should be modular and totally independent.

Comment: @Victor K I think what you need is to use `Factory-Pattern` alongside the strategy one. In that case you would solve most of your requests. Take a look at my answer to check if that is what you're looking for.

Comment: @Victor K Hi Victor, if you found this answer helpful, please consider accepting it, so that other users can benefit from it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very good question on `design-patterns` with `VBA`.

A full description of `strategy pattern` can be seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), but to summarize, this is a UML class and sequence diagram describing it:

[image]

- ## Summary

Basically, this strategy lets the algorithm vary independently from clients that use it.

> Deferring the decision about which algorithm to use until runtime allows the calling code to be more flexible and reusable.

You proposed this two solutions and I want to explain why I didn't used them:

- Wrapping `DatabaseStrategy` around Record specific to the Record and the application (`DatabaseStrategy.Create(Record).Save`)

  > Using this solution would decrease [cohesion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)), beacuse the `class` DatabaseStrategy would have to take care of instantiating `Record` `objects` (which as I show later, this can be done applying `Factory-Pattern`)
- Exposing `DatabaseStrategy` as a member of the Record but then it seems that application has to know that `DatabaseStrategy` is a member of the record (`Record.DatabaseStrategy.Save`)

  > This design pattern MUST know the strategy, but the innovation is that it can be changed at runtime, passing the desidered strategy object that implements the action methods. In this case I would move `DatabaseStrategy` away from `Record`, because the last-mentioned is the `object` that needs to be saved, but it's not the agent who performs the action (which could be a `Database` `class` as I'll show later).

To solve the problem of how to instantiate this `objects` with VBA `class` constructors that don't accept arguments, I used another pattern: the [Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

[image]

The code below is written just to illustrate how to use these two patterns, so many functions are omitted and there's no real implementation of the database methods. Now here's the rest of the code:

- ## Code

> **IRecord** `class` (**Interface**):

```
Public Function getValue() As String: End Function
Public Function setValue(stringValue As String): End Function
```

---

> **Record** `class`: 
>   This class basically represent a database record. To keep it simple, we only have a `value` property, but a real implementation would be different of course.

```
Implements IRecord
Private value As String

Private Function IRecord_getValue() As String
    IRecord_getValue = value
End Function

Private Function IRecord_setValue(stringValue As String)
    value = stringValue
End Function
```

---

> **IConnectionStrategy** `class` (**Interface**)
>   This is the Interface of Connection strategy. Little is changed from your code here.

```
Public Function Save(ByVal record As IRecord): End Function
```

---

> **ConnectionStrategyA** `class` 
>   Class for Strategy A. Little is changed from your code here.

```
Implements IConnectionStrategy
Private connectionString As String

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    connectionString = "DRIVER=Oracle Server;SERVER=myA.server.com\DatabaseA;"
End Sub

'Implements Strayegy A
Private Function IConnectionStrategy_Save(ByVal record As IRecord)
    Debug.Print "Saving to ", connectionString, "Record with value:", record.getValue
End Function
```

---

> **ConnectionStrategyB** `class` 
>   Class for Strategy A. Little is changed from your code here.

```
Implements IConnectionStrategy
Private connectionString As String

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    connectionString = "DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=myB.server.com\DatabaseB;"
End Sub

'Implements Strategy B
Private Function IConnectionStrategy_Save(ByVal record As IRecord)
    Debug.Print "Saving to ", connectionString, "Record with value:", record.getValue
End Function
```

---

> **Database** `class` 
>   This is the class that handles the connection with a database. A connection strategy defines how to connect to the database. 
>   Note that you can change the strategy without having to recast the object, just invoke `setConnectionStrategy(...)`

```
Private connection As IConnectionStrategy

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    'Initialize everything but strategy.
End Sub

'Funzione che verrà richiamata per inizializzare le propietà della classe
Public Sub InitiateProperties(ByVal connectionStrategy As IConnectionStrategy)
    Set connection = connectionStrategy
End Sub

Public Sub saveRecord(ByVal record As IRecord)
    connection.Save record
End Sub

Public Sub setConnectionStrategy(ByVal strategy As IConnectionStrategy)
    connection = strategy
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    'close connections
End Sub
```

---

> **DatabaseFactory** `Module` (VBA doesn't have static class, so use a Module instead) 
>   This class is responsible for the instantiation of your `Database Objects`

```
'Instantiate a Database with given Strategy
Public Function createDatabaseWithStrategy(strategy As IConnectionStrategy) As Database
    Set createDatabaseWithStrategy = New Database
    CreateFoglioIdro.InitiateProperties connectionStrategy:=strategy
End Function

'Instantiate a Database with Strategy A
Public Function createDatabaseWithStrategyA() As Database
    Set createDatabaseWithStrategyA = New Database
    createDatabaseWithStrategyA.InitiateProperties connectionStrategy:=New ConnectionStrategyA
End Function

'Instantiate a Database with Strategy B
Public Function createDatabaseWithStrategyB() As Database
    Set createDatabaseWithStrategyB = New Database
    createDatabaseWithStrategyB.InitiateProperties connectionStrategy:=New ConnectionStrategyB
End Function
```

---

And finally an example of application (`App Module`):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ApplicationA()
    Dim record As IRecord
    Set record = New record
    record.setValue ("This is a value")

    Dim db As Database
    Set db = DatabaseFactory.createDatabaseWithStrategyA
    db.saveRecord record
    'Prints-> Saving to     DRIVER=Oracle Server;SERVER=myA.server.com\DatabaseA;   Record with value:          This is a value
End Sub

Public Sub ApplicationB()
    Dim record As IRecord
    Set record = New record
    record.setValue ("This is a value")

    Dim db As Database
    Set db = DatabaseFactory.createDatabaseWithStrategyB
    db.saveRecord record
    'Prints-> Saving to     DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=myB.server.com\DatabaseB;      Record with value:          This is a value
End Sub
```

As you can see, `strategy-pattern` combined with `Factory-Pattern`, helps you eliminating most of the repetitive code to initialize and set a strategy for your Database `class`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Louis, that's an extensive answer, thank you! I completely forgot I asked the question, so it took me a while to get back to it. In the meantime I went with a different solution: `UnitOfWork` class that knows about the database connection and takes `ADO Commands`, and multiple `Crud` classes (same interface) for each type of record that create commands for `UnitOfWork` to transact. I will study your solution as I am certain I can learn a lot from it and use it in the future. Thank you for your answer once again!

Comment: @VictorK You're very welcome, I'm happy that you come up with another solution in the mean time, I wish I could answer this question before. Thank you for accepting the answer nonetheless! :)